# How to count image download in wordpress default gallery?

Tags: wordpress, image, download, gallery, wallpaper

Here is this code of while loop so and how to count download image, and like on images so this is my while loop so I get images use this code

```
<div class="row">
            <?php
            /* The loop */
            while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
                if ( get_post_gallery() ) :
                    $gallery = get_post_gallery( get_the_ID(), false );
                 foreach( $gallery['src'] as $src ) : 
                 ?>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="image-download-wrap">
                        <div class="image-show-box">
                            <img src="<?php echo $src; ?>" class="img img-responsive">
                            <div class="img-bottom-wrap">
                                <div class="download-btn pull-left">
                                    <a href="<?php echo $src; ?>" download><i class="fa fa-cloud-download" aria-hidden="true"></i>      Download</a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="view-btn pull-left">
                                    <i class="fa fa-download" aria-hidden="true"></i>50055
                                </div>
                                <div class="like-wrap pull-right">
                                    <span><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up" aria-hidden="true"></i> 5000</a></span>
                                    <span><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-down" aria-hidden="true"></i> 500</a></span>
                                </div>
                                <div style="clear:both;"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
              <?php
        endforeach;
    endif;
endwhile; ?>
    </div>
```

Comment: what issue you have in this code

Comment: code is perfect but i want to count how much time download image and likes on image.?? How i do that..?@MuhammadMuazzam